# Named MaterialPageRoute?

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently have

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/second", arguments: contact);
```

...

How would one rewrite this as a `MaterialPageRoute`?

```
Contact contact = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

.

```
'/second': (BuildContext context) => ViewContact(),
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use pushNamed/pushReplacementNamed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes We can do this by passing the name in the route setting parameter of material page route. Please refer to the following piece of code:

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => VendorDetailScreen(widget.vendor),//pass any arguments
            settings: RouteSettings(name: "vendorScreen")),//assign a name for the screen
```

In this way we can assign the name to the material page route. Now your navigation stack will have a route with the name "vendorScreen" after you push the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MaterialPageRoute` passing `contact` as argument in this way:

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => ViewContact(contact)));
}
```

And then in the ViewContact page:

```
class ViewContact extends StatelessWidget {
   Contact contact;
   ViewContact(this.contact);
 
   ...

}
```

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, I can't do that as I'm already using named routes. With this in mind, is it not possible to use a MaterialPageRoute for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you were asking for something like that:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ViewContact(contact),
          ),
);
```

Comment: Hi MerMonkey, I'm afraid not. I'm trying to use `MaterialPageRoute` with a named route. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: If u want to use pushReplacement it's not really a bad thing to use it like that. I also faced this problem and just did same way, because it was taking too much of my time to find out more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I'll have to make do with the `pushReplacementNamed` and just add a back button on the appbar, change the page animation etc.

Comment: You don't need to do it manualy if you got built in appbar and u will use `push` instead you will get the arrow functionality and the back button on android will also pop this page from stack and get back

Comment: Okay, I tried that - I'm using `pushReplacementNamed` and I don't have the back arrow. I did have one when using `MaterialPageRoute`. Do you know how to get it to show when using `push`?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics I think you should read this

Comment: I have. When manually adding an arrow with `Navigator.pop(context)`, I get a black screen on the `onPress`

Comment: I've solved it. Thank you for your help MerMonkey. Much appreciated